# Chartjs chart not rendering with pug template

Tags: node.js, express, pug, chart.js

I'm trying to use chartjs to render a chart in a pug template but for some reason it's not working, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? The pug file loads just fine but there's no chart on it. Here's my pug template:

```
div(class="main container-fluid text-center")
    div(class="choices")
        h2
        p I'm voting for:
        select(class="form-control")
            option 1
            option 2
            option 3
            option 4
            option 5
    div(class="chart")        
    canvas(id="chartPic" width="400" height="400")
script(src="chart.js")
script. 
    -window.onload(
    -var ctx = document.getElementById("chartPic").getContext('2d');
       -var chart = new Chart(ctx,  {
            -type: 'pie',
            -data: {
                -labels: ["red", "green", "blue"],
                -datasets: [{
                    -label: 'Number of votes',
                    -data: [1, 1, 1],
                    -backgroundColor: ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
                    -borderColor: ['green', 'blue', 'red'],
                    -borderWidth: 1
                }],
                },
            -options: {
                -title: { 
                    -display: true,
                    -text: "chart",
                },
                -legend: {
                    -position: 'bottom'
                },
            }
        });
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues with your code ...

**1 .** There's a syntax error! You need to put `,` after the end of `data` object

**2 .** You need to pass the color values as a string *(unless they are predefined variables)*

also, you should probably wrap the chart generating code inside a window onload event to make sure the code doesn't get executed before the `chart.js` script is loaded successfully.

```
div(class="main container-fluid text-center")
    div(class="choices")
        h2
        p I'm voting for:
        select(class="form-control")
            option 1
            option 2
            option 3
            option 4
            option 5
    div(class="chart")        
    canvas(id="chartPic" width="400" height="400")
script(src="chart.js")
script. 
    -window.onload = function() {
    -var red="#{red}", green="#{green}", blue="#{blue}";
    -var ctx = document.getElementById("chartPic").getContext('2d');
       -var chart = new Chart(ctx,  {
            -type: 'pie',
            -data: {
                -labels: ["red", "green", "blue"],
                -datasets: [{
                    -label: 'Number of votes',
                    -data: [1, 1, 1],
                    -backgroundColor: [red, green, blue],
                    -borderColor: [green, blue, red],
                    -borderWidth: 1
                }],
                },
            -options: {
                -title: { 
                    -display: true,
                    -text: "chart",
                },
                -legend: {
                    -position: 'bottom'
                },
            }
        });
        };
```

also, have a look at this [**working chart demo on JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kanfdk3o/) <sup>raw-js</sup>

Comment: Thank you! It's still not rendering though, I'm not getting any errors but it's not showing up either?

Comment: hmm.. maybe something's wrong with the template then

Comment: the first part of the page renders just fine, it's only the chart that's not rendering, so it seems like the template is ok but I think I'm doing something wrong with the chart. I could be wrong though..

Comment: as you can clearly see on the demo, the chart works perfectly. try putting the chart generating code inside `window.onload` event

Comment: your `window.onload` event is incorrect. it should be `window.onload = function() {... codes to exec. ...}`

Comment: ok I got it working but I'm having trouble accessing variables I'm trying to pass on the server-side using render(template, options), I'm using #{variable} in my template but it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @Keli hm.. I believe you already figured it out, didn't you? anyway, in case you didn't, please check the updated answer with the correct template format.